1990s-early 2000s sci-fi TV show about aliens who came to earth and had beautiful white ships
I vaguely remember it from my childhood and can’t find it. It would be late 1990s-early 2000s TV show about aliens show came to earth and had beautiful white ships and they were supposedly helping us but in reality there were some mysterious incidents that were likely linked to their experiments or something along those lines.
I remember in one scene a dead woman’s mouth opens and a butterfly comes out and opens its wings. It also had a modern melody with opera-like singing in the opening scenes/credits.

What country was it broadcast in, what language?

That's Earth: Final Conflict, a science fiction TV show from the 90s produced by Majel Barrett based on ideas by Gene Roddenberry.
The aliens were the Taelons, who in reality were seeking a cure for their racial sterility.  The Taelons recruited humans to work for them in various roles — humans recruited to work as their heads of security were given CVIs (cyber-viral implants) which enforced their loyalty and gave them a range of enhancements, such as eidetic memory, resistance to alcohol etc.
Season one follows William Boone, a police officer who becomes a Taelon security officer.  He is, however, a double agent for the human resistance, who are skeptical of the benefits the Taelons bring with them, and his CVI is sabotaged so he retains his free will.
The butterfly incident you remember is from the episode "Float Like a Butterfly", and I think that image appeared in the opening credits throughout Season 1.
